# How to fix this Keyword not supported "provider" for C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

First, I had similar problem Keyword not supported for "metadata". So, I wrote data source instead of metadata. After that, I tried to create Controller for ASP.NET MVC and that show me Keyword not supported for "provider". I read the some case for SQL SERVER connection, but I didn't found for Oracle connection. 
Here is my connectionStrings in web.config file.

```
   <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MVC-20170801212521;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MVC-20170801212521.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="EntitiesLL" connectionString="Data Source=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;data source=****:1111/xe;password=******;user id=******;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />   
   </connectionStrings>
```

Thank you.

Comment: The connectionString does not look at all like a connectionString for Oracle, see https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this

```
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Something tells me it should be `OracleClient`.

Comment: Nope. Maybe, it's problem with this PROVIDER=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

Comment: Well, they have to agree. What DB platform are you using and where did you get the connection string?

Comment: I use Oracle SQL Developer. I generated my connection string with EZ Connect when I was creating models.

Answer (score 0):

According to [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28844/installation.htm#CHDFFEIB) this should read:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MVC-20170801212521;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MVC-20170801212521.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="EntitiesLL" connectionString="Data Source=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;data source=****:1111/xe;password=******;user id=******;" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />   
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Ok. Now, I have new problem. :( Unable to retrieve metadata for 'MVC.Models.JOB'. Unable to find requested .net framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.

Comment: As for 'MVC.Models.JOB' - didn't  Oracle SQL Developer generate some additional assembly with model types?

As for missing driver - well, is it installed? You can get it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)